# JQuery Scrollable scrolls further than actually wanted

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tools, jquery-scrollable

I'm using JQuery Scrollables to display an image gallery, see http://www.mba-europe.de/lehr_veroff.html

In my setup, I have a `.bscrollable` `DIV` that contains a `.bitems` `DIV` that contains all the `.item` `DIV`'s in analogy to `.scrollable`, `.items` and `.item` from the JQuery Scrollables demo page.

However, as you can see, scrolling doesn't stop as soon as the last element in the list is reached. Instead, the user can scroll further until only the last element is visible, followed by (in my case) three empty slots.

How do I avoid scrolling further, such that there are always no less than four elements visible?

Best regards,
Philip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `scrollable`'s api to achive that like this;

```
var $scrollables = $('.bscrollable').scrollable({
    size: 4,
    mousewheel: true,
    vertical: false,
    horizontal: true
}).data('scrollable');
$scrollables.onBeforeSeek(function(e, i) {
    var threshold = $scrollables.getSize() - 4;
    if(i > threshold) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/karalamalar/uh2gk/)

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I wanted to achieve. Thank you! (You'll receive the bounty as soon as this is possible)